# Delete and restore item(s) from Listview

Tags: android, checkbox, arraylist, android-listview, baseadapter

I have a listview in my main.xml and a a few checkbox in a different xml called options.
The listview is hooked to a custombaseadapter and gets filled with items.
I want the user to be able to delete and restore items (preferable at the same position) from the listview through the checkboxes by checking or unchecking them.
My question is how can i use the baseadapter to do this?
Any help and some example code is highly appreciated.
Thx.

Baseadapter code:

```
public class MyCustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private static ArrayList<SearchResults> searchArrayList;

  private LayoutInflater mInflater;


 public MyCustomBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SearchResults> results) {
   searchArrayList = results;
   mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
  }


public int getCount() {
   return searchArrayList.size();
  }

 public Object getItem(int position) {
   return searchArrayList.get(position);
  }

 public long getItemId(int position) {
   return position;
  }

 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   ViewHolder holder;
   if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.test, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.txtNaam = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.naam);
    holder.txtWaarde = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.waarde);

   convertView.setTag(holder);
   } else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
   }

   holder.txtNaam.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getNaam());
   holder.txtWaarde.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getWaarde());

  return convertView;
  }

 static class ViewHolder {
   TextView txtNaam;
   TextView txtWaarde;
  }


}
```

OnReadyListner in my main xml, ready, ready1, ready2, are the names for the individual checkboxes:

```
private class OnReadyListenerBeltegoed implements MyBeltegoed.ReadyListener { 

    public void ready(boolean niewbel) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
    } 

    public void ready1(boolean vorige) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

    } 

    public void ready2(boolean teg_tot) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

    } 
}
```

Code in the options xml file where the checkboxes are:

```
public class MyBeltegoed extends Dialog  {

public interface ReadyListener { 
    public void ready(boolean nieuwbel); 
    public void ready1(boolean vorige); 
    public void ready2(boolean teg_tot); 
    public void ready3(boolean verbruik_teg); 
    public void ready4(boolean ongebruik_teg); 
    public void ready5(boolean boven_bundel); 
    public void ready6(boolean niet_bundel); 
} 

private ReadyListener readyListener; 

public MyBeltegoed(Context context, ReadyListener readyListener) { 
    super(context); 
    this.readyListener = readyListener; 
} 


@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

    setContentView(com.sencide.R.layout.beltegoed); 

    Button buttonOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBel); 
    buttonOk.setOnClickListener(new OKListener()); 

} 

private class OKListener implements android.view.View.OnClickListener { 

    public void onClick(View v) { 
        CheckBox niewbel = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.nieuwbel); 
        readyListener.ready(niewbel.isChecked()); 

        CheckBox vorige = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.vorige); 
        readyListener.ready1(vorige.isChecked()); 
      }
    }
```